# Filter custom attribute in product collection

Tags: magento2, product, collection, template, object-manager

I have created a custom attribute with name product_deisgn_proof.
I want to filter this attribute using product collection in custom template file. When I try to fetch collection of product in an array it gives product_design_proof undefined index.
Here is the code I am using to filter the attribute in product collection.
[image]

Please give me a better solution to fetch the product collection with filter attribute.

Comment: Can anyone give me solution of this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

try below code

Using **ObjectManger**

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
//get current product
$currentProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$currentProductData = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($currentProduct->getId());

echo $currentProductData->getId();
echo $currentProductData->getName();

$customise = $currentProductData->getProductDesignProof();


/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
/** Apply filters here */
$collection = $productCollection
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('product_design_proof', $customise)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status',Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
            ->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){
     echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
}  
?>
```

best way to create the block and pass product data to the template file.

I hope this will help you..!